# Android back button doesn't work correctly in CupertinoTabBar apps

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

How can I set up a native back button on Android devices when using CupertinoTAbScaffold?So that she does not close the application, but returns back. I tried to solve with the method which is described in this question: [Flutter : CupertinoTabScaffold - Back button close app on Android from TabView's navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141565/flutter-cupertinotabscaffold-back-button-close-app-on-android-from-tabviews). But the method presented in this question does not work. How can this be implemented?
Help fix the problem, please.
My Code:

```js
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> firstTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> secondTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> thirdTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  CupertinoTabController? tabController;

  //widgets in tabs
  List<Widget> data = [
    ImagePickerScreen(),
    DataPickerScreen(),
    UserDataScreen()
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    tabController = CupertinoTabController(initialIndex: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //making a list of the keys
    final listOfKeys = [firstTabNavKey, secondTabNavKey, thirdTabNavKey];
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return !await listOfKeys[tabController!.index]
              .currentState!
              .maybePop();
        },
        child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.circle),
                label: 'Image Picker',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.calendar),
                label: 'Data Picker',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.pencil),
                label: 'User Data',
              ),
            ],
          ),
          tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return CupertinoTabView(
              navigatorKey: listOfKeys[index],
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return data[index];
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have localisation enabled, or show us `MaterialApp` part

Comment: What do you mean by MaterialApp part? 
This error appeared after I added the code from the question that I attached in the description: when i added the GlobalKeys

Comment: As the previous commenter asked, can you please share the root part of the code of your application - the `MaterialApp` or `CuppertinoApp` part - in it's entirety? Also please shared the error from the console, instead of the screenshot of the error on emulator.

Comment: looks like you are using `CupertinoApp` instead of `MaterialApp`. am I right?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, only the back button on Android does not work as it should